# Android canvas. contains(x, y) for an oval?

Tags: android, canvas

Creating android 2d game.
...The character has obstacles, where he must not go.
Basicaly it is implemented like:

```
RectF obstacle1 = new RectF(100, 150, 200, 300);
Paint paint = new Paint();
barPaint.setColor(Color.argb(130, 255, 255, 255));
canvas.drawRect(obstacle1, paint);

// stopping the character in case of getting to the obstacle

if (obstakle1.contains(currentXCoordinate, currentYCoordinate) {
    theCharacter.stop(); 
}
//...
```

and works fine for rectangle - shaped obstacles.

But I have to use oval - shaped obstacles.
If i do the same and just draw oval:

```
RectF ovalObstacle = new RectF(100, 400, 500, 800);
Paint paint = new Paint();
barPaint.setColor(Color.argb(130, 255, 255, 255));
// drawing oval
canvas.drawOval(ovalObstacle, paint);

// stopping the character in case of getting to the obstacle    
if (ovalObstacle.contains(currentXCoordinate, currentYCoordinate) {
    theCharacter.stop(); 
}
```

the character will stop when he reach the RectF, not the oval itself     (light circle on the printscreen)
([image: print screen]

Is there a way to use something like method contains(x, y) for an oval?
To figure out when the character will reach the oval or circle itself?

Or how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method check whether the point is in the oval or not.

```
public boolean pointInEllipse(Point test, Point center, int width, int height) {
        int dx = test.x - center.x;
        int dy = test.y - center.y;
        return (dx * dx) / (width * width) + (dy * dy) / (height * height) <= 1;
    }
```

I got the reference from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse)

[image]

Comment: right but width you mean the radius in x and height is the radius in y

Comment: here width refers to semi major axis and height refers to semi minor axis.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. Works but with 2 times bigger radius. Figuring out what's wrong

Comment: yeah already understood this. Works perfect with using of horisontal and vertical radius.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Phytagoras.

```
float delPos=(player.x-obstacle.x)*(player.x-obstacle.x)+
             (player.y-obstacle.y)*(player.y-obstacle.y);
if(delPos<=radius*radius)
{
    //collision
}
```

dont use Math.sqrt() because its too slow!

This method is not for ovals but its easier to use a circle shaped hitbox. make your life easier!!!

for ellipse its like

```
boolean collision=(player.x - obstacle.x)² / obstacle.width/2² + 
                  (player.y - obstacle.y)² / obstacle.height/2² <=1;
if(collision)
{
    //collision
}
```

Comment: works but  for the radius bigger than it actually is. What do you mean by radius variable? I it is an oval should it be radis1*radius2?

Comment: no the upper one is only for a circle like i said the bottom one is for the ellipse